# Is there a difference in definition between an increasing sequence and a monotonically increasing sequence?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, definition

Is there a difference in definition between an increasing sequence and a monotonically increasing sequence?

In some places I see they call it just inc/decreasing and some call it monotonically inc/decreasing, is there a difference?

Can we say that for example, if a sequence increases for only some of its indices then it's increasing but not monotonically? Like for example $(-1)^n n$ which has an increasing subsequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A monotone sequence is a sequence that is increasing or decreasing.
$$\begin{align}
\text{monotone increasing}&=\text{increasing}\\
\text{monotone decreasing}&=\text{decreasing}
\end{align}$$